# CSS pushing form field down

Tags: css, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a CSS problem whereby the CSS on focus on a form field in pushing the form field adjacent to it down to the next level. I have tried various things, such as changing the width and the display settings, but it's still pushing it down.

Before Focus

[image: Before Focus]

On Focus

[image: On Focus]

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I don't have that issue on the website you mentioned, tried Firefox and Chrome

Comment: I'm not seeing this on the live site with Chrome v 39.0.2171.95 m. What browser is that happening on?

Comment: It was happening on Chrome Version 37.0.2062.124 . It's now been fixed by Casey Rule's answer. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS, and the formatting should be fixed:

```
.gform_wrapper .ginput_complex .ginput_left {
    clear: left;
}

.gform_wrapper .ginput_complex .ginput_right {
    clear: right;
}
```

While I can't reproduce your problem on any of my browsers, I suspect from your screenshot that the Zip Code field is essentially trying to be on the same line as the City field.  Adding clear rules will force the fields to go to the next line.